# GM_xmlhttpRequest: No headers found on res.readyState === 2 (HEADERS_RECEIVED CODE)

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, greasemonkey, userscripts

I'm having trouble getting the results that I want from my Userscript Ajax request.

Below you will see my code. I know it generally works for a fact, since I've managed to receive data via this very function using readyState === 4 / onload.

However, I am loading images, of which I only really need the headers. That is why it would be ideal (and for a matter of fact it is actually unusable at this state) if I could load just the headers, which I did:

```
var get_img_type = function(url, callback) {
  var header;
  for (var n = 0; n < valid_image_types.length; n++) {
    (function (n) {
      var ret = GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: "GET",
        url: preview_to_full(url, valid_image_types[n]),
        onreadystatechange: function(res) {
          if (res.readyState === 2)  { // HEADERS_RECEIVED
            console.log(res);
            header = getHeader("Content-Type", res.responseHeaders);
            if (header == valid_image_types[n]) {
              callback(header);
            }
          }
        }
      });
    })(n);
  }
};
```

However, this simply doesn't work.

Analyzing the results on my 53.0 Firefox Developer Console, it doesn't seem like any DATA AT ALL, let alone headers, are being loaded:

```
{ context: null, finalUrl: null, lengthComputable: null, loaded: null, readyState: 2, response: "", responseHeaders: null, responseText: "", responseXML: null, status: null, ... }
```

The same goes for state 3 (the partial state), by the way, although I cannot paste the results here, as they're quite massive (just gibberish, though).

What am I doing wrong? How can I fulfill my original intention?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could it be this 11 year old bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=343769 ?

Comment: @wOxxOm Could be! Although that would suck. I've already spent a couple of hours writing some 500 lines of code, and due to the site's denying developers of using the API, that's the only way I can identify image types solely by their thumbnail. I hope there's a solution.

Comment: If you only need the headers, why are you using a `GET` request instead of a `HEAD` request?  Reference: https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest#HEAD_request

Comment: @wOxxOm, that bug is listed as resolved.

Comment: That `resolved` means `WORKSFORME` which doesn't mean much actually.